# Unable to use Model Classes "Does not Contain deffination for Class Name"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i am following Mvc MysicStore , Project . In my model class i have  Genre.cs

```
namespace MvcMusicStore.Models
{
    public class Genre
    {
        public int GenreId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Descriptio { get; set; }

        public List<Album> albums { get; set; }

    }
}
```

and same way 2 more classes like Artis.cs  Album,cs  and Genre.cs .

**Genre.cs**

```
namespace MvcMusicStore.Models
{
    public partial class Genre
    {
        public int GenreId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public List<Album> Albums { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Album.cs**

```
namespace MvcMusicStore.Models
{
    public class Album
    {
        public int AlbumId     { get; set; }
        public int GenreId     { get; set; }
        public int ArtistId    { get; set; }

        public string Title    { get; set; }

        public decimal Price   { get; set; }
        public string AlbumUrl { get; set; }

        public Genre genre     { get; set; }
        public Artist artist   { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My problem is that when i try to use these classes with sample data it says

[image]

i have made sure there are no namespace issues and i have created a class SampleData.cs that has following code that gives error

```
new List<Album>
            {
                new Album { Title = "The Best Of Men At Work", 
                Genre = genres.Single(g => g.Name == "Rock"),
                Price = 8.99M, Artist = artists.Single(a => a.Name == "Men At Work")
                , AlbumArtUrl = "/Content/Images/placeholder.gif" },
```

it shows me above mentioned error for this code whats wrong with it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your property is written in lowercase and you try to access it as `Genre`. Try renaming it.

It's because your `Album` class doesn't have a `Genre` property, but a `genre`property.

Instead of

```
public Genre genre     { get; set; }
```

try

```
public Genre Genre     { get; set; }
```